# 32-ARM CPU, debugging registers

Tags: debug, arm, flag

Greeting,
I have a question about 32-bit ARM CPU debugging registers. I want to set up a breakpoint in the program and want to repeatedly break the program at this point without manually inserting the breakpoint again. But I cannot find the debug control flag in ARM CPU that is similar to the RF flag in x86 CPU. If I manually insert the beakpoint in the program, after handling the debug exception, I need to disable the breakpoint and manually set the beakpoint again. Does ARM CPU allow me to set some control flags to disable the debug exception temporarily for next instruction? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Could you just increase PC on process stack?

Comment: If I increase PC on the process stack before returning to the process, how can I execute the instruction where the breakpoint is inserted?